# Combining mixed data types in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe called 'Year'. When I invoke;

```
filtered_df['Year'].unique()
```

My result is:

> array([2013, 2012, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, '2011',
>          '2010', '2015', '2009', 'N 117 ST / GREENWOOD AV N'], dtype=object)

I would like to combine the results of the `'2011','2010', '2015', and '2009'` instances with that of their non-string counterparts. I thought it might be possible to do so using a regular expression, but the only things I have attempted thus far have returned errors that make me believe that my methodology is inherently flawed, so I have not included them here.

Any ideas for a computationally efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: What is your expected output? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: If you do decide to try regex, I highly recommend googling for an "online regex tester" such as https://pythex.org/.  I find them invaluable for writing and testing regex expressions before coding it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually we convert it to numeric values (all non-convertable values will be converted into `NaN`'s) in the following way:

```
filtered_df['Year'] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_df['Year'], errors='coerce')
```